# netbeans, Qt, & Qmake "command not found"

Tags: qt, netbeans, qmake

All,

I am (trying to) using Netbeans to build a simple Qt app (from a tutorial) and I cannot build it because I get this error:

```
    /C/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/qmake/qmake.exe VPATH=. -spec win32-g++ -o qttmp-Debug.mk nbproject/qt-Debug.pro
    make[1]:/C/Qt/2010.02.1/qt/qmake/qmake.exe: Command not found
```

when the file is exactly there, and I can open a terminal and execute it.

Note in the error message: "/C/Qt..."  The actual path is C:/Qt...
I have used the tools/options/c++ dialog to browse to the file and select it, and it is specified as C:\Qt... just like all the other tools.  What is corrupting the C: and making it /C/ ?

Now, if I remove the path to qmake, and have it use the PATH environment variable, it finds it, but then it fails due to 'multiple targets'...

Obviously, pilot error, but where?  I have seen several posts on this, and they all say to make sure it is in the path, and it is, so now what?  (I can open a terminal and type 'qmake' and I get the 'Usage: qmake..." so I know it is visible.

Windows 7, Netbeans 7.0, MinGW (I also have cygwin installed...).

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

:bp:

Addenda:  I changed the path to my 'make' to use the MinGW one rather than the cygqin one, and now it can find qmake, but I get other errors:  'Could not find mkspecs for your QMAKESPEC(win32-g++) after trying:...

Any additional thoughts?

Comment: Did this ever get figured out? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QMake requires more than just a path to work correctly.  On my Windows box, there is a menu option for 'Qt Command Prompt' under the 'Qt SDK 2010.05' group in the Start Menu.  Running it produces the following:

```
Setting up a MinGW/Qt only environment...
-- QTDIR set to C:\Qt\2010.05\qt
-- PATH set to C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\bin
-- Adding C:\Qt\2010.05\bin to PATH
-- Adding C:\WINDOWS\System32 to PATH
-- QMAKESPEC set to win32-g++
```

You will want to make sure the environment you launch qmake in has all of those set.

The most probable reason you are see '/C/...' is because you are causing a mingw shell to run when you execute your build.

Comment: sorry for the late acknowledgement.  Thanks!

Comment: I've tried that, but the problem seems to be persisting for me. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: I'd first make sure that the proper locations are being setup in the environment, they will change with different installs.  I also remember having some strange issues if "COMSPEC" was not manually set, but I believe this was only for cross-compiling QNX Qt apps on Windows using QNX Momentics.